# Can't remove columns from a dataframe, output turns into a logical vector

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, splitstackshape, csplit

There seems to be something wrong with the `data.frame` I get from the `cSplit` function.

I can't extract columns without `NAs` from using the code below:

```
data_places <- data_table[ , colSums(is.na(data_table)) == 0 ]
```

The output is a `Named logi` vector rather than a `data.frame` that doesn't have columns that possess rows with NAs.

The issue is mainly due to the `data.frame` output of the `cSplit` function of of the `splitstackshape` package. The issue also appears using the `data.table` package.

I tried creating a new `data.frame` that extracts the columns of the `data.frame` output of the `cSplit` function and the code above works fine.

Any ideas what's wrong with `cSplit`'s `data.frame` output?

Here's a sample of my code:

```
library(splitstackshape)
data <- data.frame(V1=c("Place1-Place1-Place1-Place1-Place3-Place5",
          "Place1-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place3-Place5-Place5",
          "Place6-Place6",
          "Place1-Place2-Place3-Place4"))

data_table <- cSplit(data, "V1", sep="-", direction = "wide")
data_places <- data_table[ , colSums(is.na(data_table)) == 0 ]
data_places
str(data_places)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `with=FALSE` as the output of `cSplit` is a `data.table` object.

```
data_table[ , colSums(is.na(data_table)) == 0 , with=FALSE]
#      V1_1   V1_2
#1: Place1 Place1
#2: Place1 Place4
#3: Place6 Place6
#4: Place1 Place2
```

If we look at the `?data.table`

> with - 
>    By default with=TRUE and j is evaluated within the frame of x;
>   column names can be used as variables. When with=FALSE j is a
>   character vector of column names or a numeric vector of column
>   positions to select, and the value returned is always a data.table.
>   with=FALSE is often useful in data.table to select columns
>   dynamically.

---

Another option would be to use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) all(!is.na(x)), data_table)
```